# Sqoop jobs are failing with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: begin > end in range (begin, end): (1470951003366, 1470951003021)

Tags: sqoop, oozie

Earlier also I have faced this issue, in order to resolve this, I have scheduled the same oozie(sqoop+Hive jobs)jobs with crontab tool. so after scheduling with crontab we have not faced this issue(reason for scheduling with tab is because there was time skew between the nodes in the cluster).
Right now. again facing the same issue.so is there any solutions for it?

Thanks in advance.

Note: Earlier these oozie jobs were scheduled with oozie coordination jobs (reference [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407959/getting-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-begin-end-in-range-begin-end-w) which was asked before).

Error Logs:

> Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], main() threw exception, begin > end in range (begin, end): (1470951003366, 1470951003021)
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: begin > end in range (begin, end): (1470951003366, 1470951003021)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.protocolrecords.impl.pb.GetApplicationsRequestPBImpl.setStartRange(GetApplicationsRequestPBImpl.java:340)
>           at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMainHadoopUtils.getChildYarnJobs(LauncherMainHadoopUtils.java:68)
>           at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMainHadoopUtils.killChildYarnJobs(LauncherMainHadoopUtils.java:88)
>           at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:168)
>           at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:47)
>           at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:46)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:236)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Comment: can you provide your sqoop query

Comment: sqoop job --create job_Name --meta-connect "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://Server_name:16000/sqoop" -- import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://IP_ADDRESS;username=****;password=******;database=*****" --target-dir /user/home/data/employee --query 'SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6.col7, AS plant FROM db.tablename WHERE $CONDITIONS' -m 1 --fields-terminated-by '|'

Comment: This is the sqoop job i have created , i am importing the table data from MS SQL server and importing updating to hive tables.

Comment: @Neethu. any inputs from your side on this issue.